# If all primes in the prime factor decomposistion of both $m , n$ occur at powers $\geq 2$, and $ \phi (m) = \phi (n)$, then m = n.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that, if all primes in the prime factor decomposition of both *m* and *n*
occur at powers $\geq 2$, and $\phi (m)= \phi (n)$, then *m* = *n*.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $p$ divides $m$ and $n$ to exactly the same power $a$, i.e. $v_p(n)=v_p(m)=a$. Then
$$\varphi\left(\frac{m}{p^a}\right)=\frac{\varphi(m)}{p^{a-1}(p-1)}=\frac{\varphi(n)}{p^{a-1}(p-1)}=\varphi\left(\frac{m}{p^a}\right).$$
Thus, WLOG we can assume that for every prime $p$ dividing either $m$ or $n$, either $v_p(n)<v_p(m)$ or $v_p(n)>v_p(m)$.

Let $q$ be the largest prime going into either $m$ or $n$. WLOG, let's say that $v_q(m)>v_q(n)$.

Because
$$\varphi(m)=q^{v_q(m)-1}(q-1)\cdot X = \left.\begin{cases}
q^{v_q(n)-1}(q-1) & \text{ if }q\mid n,\\
1 & \text{ if }q\nmid n
\end{cases}\right\}\cdot Y=\varphi(n),$$
we must have that $q$ goes into $Y$; but that's impossible, because $Y$ is a product of things of the form $p^{a-1}(p-1)$ where $p$ is a prime smaller than $q$, and nothing of that form can have a factor of $q$.